# How can I link the number of satellites retrieved from GpsStatus to a specific fix recorded by LocationListener?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, locationlistener

I have been reading through the past questions on `GpsStatus` and I am confused by one issue: When I retrieve the the number of satellites used in the last fix from a `GpsStatus` object updated by my `GpsStatusListener`, how do I know that this is the same fix that has been recorded by my `LocatonListener`?

My first approach to recording the number of satellites used in a fix was to count them in the `onGpsStatusChanged` method of my `GpsStatusListener`, and pass the number to a variable that I then accessed at the top of my `LocationListener`'s `onLocationChanged` method. But I would often end up with a count of zero satellites being reported for GPS fixes, and when I logged what was going on, I found that the my `GpsStatusListener` was firing off a long stream of different satellite counts, after which my `LocationListener` was then grabbing the last one -- which often turned out to be zero even though previous ones were higher. My assumption is that this is a timing issue: The latest fix has changed between the time when the `GpSStatusListener` records the number of satellites and the time when the `LocationListener` starts its `onLocationChanged` method.

A second approach that I tried is to simply update the `GpsStatus` object within the `GpsStatusListener`, and then count the satellites from that object at the very top of my `LocationListener`'s `onLocationChanged` method (see below). However, this does not seem to solve the problem either.

Does anyone have a better approach? Or am I wrong to be worried about this timing issue?

Here is the relevant part of the code I am used for my second approach:

```
    //. . . 

private class GpsStatusListener implements GpsStatus.Listener {
    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        if (event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS) {
            if (gpsStatus != null) {
                locationManager.getGpsStatus(gpsStatus);
            }
        }
    }
}

private class mLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        GpsStatus thisFixGpsStatus = gpsStatus;
        Iterator<GpsSatellite> sats = thisFixGpsStatus.getSatellites()
                .iterator();
        satCount = 0;
        while (sats.hasNext()) {
            GpsSatellite gpsSatellite = (GpsSatellite) sats.next();
            if (gpsSatellite.usedInFix()) {
                satCount++;
            }
        } // . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this may not fully answer your question, some background info:

The number of satellites (used)  dataset is usually not provided by the GPS chip evry second. Typical values are evry 5 or 10 seconds. The reason is that the satellite constellation does not change evry second.

So probably there is no way to get the num sats syncronized to the coresponding fix on an android phone.